# How to up and run java code in JasersoftStudio?

Tags: java, jaspersoft-studio

I would like to know something if possible. As I used JaspersoftStudio, I noticed that when creating new project folder it always came up with JRE library. I also see java editor in there as well. Is it possible to write and run java code in JaspersoftStudio GUI?

Please share your ideas on here.

Regard,
Sakura

Answer (score 4):

As you may have noticed, Jaspersoft Studio is a repackaged eclipse. And yes it is possible to run Java code in it, it's just a bit more cumbersome than in vanilla eclipse.

1. In any of your jasper projects (the project icon in the explorer should have a little `J`), right click and open Properties.
2. In `Java Build Path`, add a new source folder.
3. In your new folder, create a new File, and put your main class in it.
4. You can now run it with the keyboard shortcut `Alt-Shift-x j`. I don't know if there's a menu for that too.

Additionally if you have an existing eclipse project, you can import it directly into Jaspersoft Studio using `Import... Existing Projects into Workspace`.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your step by step explanation. Such a clear one.